# What do “sogar” and “darauf” mean or refer to in this example sentence?

Tags: meaning, adverb, pronominal-adverb

I’m currently reading *Harry Potter und der Stein der Weisen*.

I am managing to comprehend a bit of it (I’m far from fluent in German) although the first sentence in the book is really confusing to me.

What I can’t seem to understand is the following sentence:

> Mr. und Mrs. Dursley im Ligusterweg Nummer 4 waren stolz
>   darauf, ganz und gar normal zu sein, sehr stolz sogar.

I would interpret that as:

> Mr and Mrs Dursley in the number 4 Privet Drive were proud (on it?) absolutely proud to be normal (very proud even?).

This just doesn’t make sense in my opinion but maybe I’m over-analyzing it? I just can’t see what the need is for the words *darauf* and *sogar* in this sentence. I’d appreciate any clarification greatly.

Answer (score 13):

The English term would be *proud of it*, and the second part would indeed be *very proud even*.

*to be proud of something* translates to *auf etwas stolz sein*. Using *darauf* instead of *auf* makes the sentence reference something which came before or afterwards in the sentence. Compare:

- > Er ist stolz auf sein Fahrrad. (He is proud of his bicycle.)
- > Er hat ein Fahrrad und ist stolz darauf. (He has a bicycle and is proud of it.)
- > Er ist stolz darauf, ein Fahrrad zu haben. (He is proud of having a bicycle.)

The *darauf* references the *ein Fahrrad haben*, the “act” of having a bicycle.

Comment: Wo ist das *sogar*? :)

Comment: Very proud indeed.

Comment: If I may add, an easy way to remember what “daruf” means is to realize that it even sounds similar to “thereof” in English: He’s got a bike and he is proud thereof.

Answer (score 6):

One translation would be

> Mr. and Mrs. Dursley were proud of being normal through and through. Very proud actually.

As Frerich said in his answer, the *darauf* indicates that the thing of which they are proud will be described in the following part of the sentence.

The word *sogar* means *even/actually/as a matter of fact*.

Answer (score 1):

Closer look on *darauf*:

> [Ich habe ein Fahrrad.]
>   Ich bin stolz auf das Fahrrad. >> I am proud of the bike.
>   Da bin ich stolz drauf. >> Of *that* , I am proud. (*Da* → *that* → having a bike)
>   Ich bin stolz darauf. >> I am proud of *it*. (*it* → having a bike)

Directly translated, “Stolz *darauf* sein” or — splitting *darauf* — “Stolz *da drauf* sein”, means something like “Being proud *on that*”.

The *r* is a binding letter:

> … auf das … -->> … d**r**auf …  [on that / of that]
>   … in dem … -->> … d**r**in …  [in{to} that]
>   … um das (herum) … -->> … darum (herum) …  [around that]

Answer (score 0):

*Darauf* is one of the *da*-adverbs that replace the construction *(preposition) etwas* in standard speech. In this case, the verb *stolz sein* requires a prepositional object with *auf,* so whatever you are proud of needs to be added with *auf.* For example:

> Ich bin stolz **auf** meinen Sohn.

In the case of your sentence, the object what they are proud of is, in fact, a complete infinitive construction. These cannot immediately follow a preposition but need to be references by a demonstrative pronoun — either using *auf das* but that is very colloquial or by using *darauf.* So the best Englihs translation for the first bit is:

> Mr and Mrs Dursley of 4 Privet Drive were proud **to be** completely and utterly normal.

*Sogar* is, as Thorsten pointed out, a kind of re-reference to the previous sentence along the lines of *even, actually* or *as a matter of fact.* So the second sentence could be translated:

> In fact, (they were) very proud.

Answer (score -1):

> Mr and Mrs Dursley in the number 4 Privet Drive were proud (on it?)
>   absolutely proud to be normal (very proud even?).

It could be translate like this:

> Mr and Mrs Dursley in the number 4 Privet Drive were **proud**, **absolutely**
>   proud to be normal.

The "**darauf**" and "**sehr sogar**" refers to "**normal**", which turns into a subject.

It tries to strengthen the verbs... typical way in german to make something even better than it actually is. If I am proud, I could be prouder, but nobody would say that, wouldn't them?

Answer (score -1):

The da comes from the Fingerzeig-"da!", it points to an to-be-emphasized entity referenced before or after - in this case being normal.

'Sogar' indices that this property of normalness is commonly being viewed unfavorably up upon so it is interpreted as being unexpectedly proud. 
(Sogar is always tied to common values and beliefs)